# What does "Separate X Screen" mean on my nvidia settings?

Tags: nvidia, video, multiple-monitors

I have 2 video cards and 3 monitors.  Earlier today, I connected my 3rd monitor.  Nothing displayed on it and my other 2 screens worked GREAT.  While tweaking, I modified my `GeForce 8400GS` so the "Configuration" was set to "Separate X Screen" which was the only option available.

[image]

Now when I hook up the 3rd monitor I see this (ignore the laptop on the right):

[image]
The 2 screens show an NVidia logo while the 3rd screen continues to be black.  Can someone explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An X Screen is basically a whole different "instance" of X. In other words, you can run Gnome on one X screen and KDE on another. What happens when you switch X screens (by pressing CTL ALT F[7-12])?

By the way, you may get more help on the forums for this complicated of an issue.

Comment: Nothing happens

Comment: Nothing? That's really weird. I hope you can get this fixed.